# How to change the position of an element from beside to under?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[Here](https://github.com/NextStepWebs/simplemde-markdown-editor) is a markdown editor which I have implemented it in the fiddled below:

```js
var simplemde = new SimpleMDE({ element: document.getElementById("txtarea") });
```

```html
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/simplemde/latest/simplemde.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/simplemde/latest/simplemde.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<textarea id="txtarea"></textarea>
```

That editor has a option named `side-by-side` which is a preview of output (it is available only on full-screen page-size (not mobile)).

Well, as you see in the fiddle, the position of that preview is next to textarea. All I need is changing the position of that to under the textarea, something like stackoverflow.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your code:

```
<style>
    .CodeMirror-sided {
      width: 100%!important;
      position: relative;
    }

    .editor-preview-side {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .CodeMirror-fullscreen {
      position: relative !important;
    }

    .CodeMirror-sided {
      width: 100%!important;
    }

</style>
```

Works fine for me :-)
https://jsfiddle.net/z375hor1/1/

Comment: You made my day ..! +1

Comment: Hi again .. I'm trying to make [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34907299/how-to-use-textarea-for-rtl-direction) right-to-left, Do you know how can I do that?